# Turning off ip spoofing check in Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, devise, environment-variables

**The problem**

I'm getting the error:

`ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::IpSpoofAttackError (IP spoofing attack?!HTTP_CLIENT_IP="203.29.78.157"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR="172.20.19.214, 116.50.58.180"):`

when some people visit my Rails 3.0.10 application and log in or confirm their email address. I'm using Devise.

**What I've tried**

http://pivotallabs.com/users/jay/blog/articles/1216-standup-4-7-2010-disabling-rails-ip-spoofing-safeguard

So within `production.rb` I've added:

`config.action_controller.ip_spoofing_check = false`

I've also tried adding it to `environment.rb`:

```
Things3::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_controller.ip_spoofing_check = false
end
```

I still get the error. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this too. Are you sure it's nothing to worry about?

Comment: I'm going to close this question because I added it to production.rb and it actually fixed the issue. What issue are you having Stephanie?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Note that the method "config.action_controller.ip_spoofing_check=" has deprecation warnings starting 3.0, and now won't work on 3.2. Use the following method call instead:

`config.action_dispatch.ip_spoofing_check = false`

Comment: Wow, is this true by default?

Comment: Yes, Nathan. It is true by default.

Comment: The new call no longer works as well, it appears the only solution is to have your web server strip one of the two tags (HTTP_CLIENT_IP or X-FORWARDED-FOR)  https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c7a283140e750800a9479f6b1736ca1f7005948/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb

Comment: This didn't work for me initially when adding it to environment.rb; but after adding it to application.rb, it worked (as of Rails 3.2.13).

Answer (score 9):

This blog post might help: it explains why this error occur and how to disable ip spoofing while retaining the security check https://github.com/phinze/writeheavy.com/blob/master/_posts/2011-07-31-when-its-ok-to-turn-of-rails-ip-spoof-checking.markdown

Comment: That link doesn't work, but found a link to the markdown on the Author's GitHub page: https://github.com/phinze/writeheavy.com/blob/master/_posts/2011-07-31-when-its-ok-to-turn-of-rails-ip-spoof-checking.markdown

Answer (score -1):

This started working for me right after I posted this. I made a mistake testing it when I'd added it to `environment.rb`.